# R + ggplot + pdf device + LaTeX: is it possible to embed fonts one time

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, latex, sweave

I'm having an r-scipt that is generaing a `PDF` in the following way...

1. 100+ graphs are beeing made with `baseplot` and `ggplot`. The graphs are generated with `pdf` device. The reason I'm using `pdf` is that I need to embed fonts (to use custom font in tex labels).
2. After graphs are generated I call `Sweave` that generates `.tex` to gather all that graphs together.
3. After that I call `MikTeX` to generate PDF.

It turns out that 75-95% of time needed to generate a graph is taken by  `embed_fonts` call. Is there a way to do less `embed_fonts` (that seems to be a wrapper for ghostscript) calls? The ideal vatiant is to embed call only one time. Is that possible?

Comment: I had similar problems when creating 4k pages PDF file. Was like 120MB big. I used acrobat professional in the end to "clean" the pdf. It was basically removing all the embedded fonts and I could save it afterwards with about 20MB. Couldn't find a better solution than this step done by hand.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gather all that graphs together'? If you mean merging all figures in one pdf, you may want to look at `pdftk` and use something like `pdftk *.pdf cat output mergedfile.pdf`. I guess you can then apply `embed_fonts` only on the merged pdf.

Comment: @DJack I mean large `tex` file with many `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pdfs/graph_made_with_R_12345.pdf}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to do `embed_fonts` over the PDF, generated on step 3 instead of calling it over each of graph generated on step 1 and that seem to be OK

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use the `cairo_pdf` device that should embed the fonts.
`cairo_pdf` seems slower than `pdf` but faster than `pdf + embedFonts`.

Of course embedding the fonts in the final pdf document only would be a better solution...

```r
library(microbenchmark)

res_pdf <- microbenchmark({
    f = tempfile(fileext = '.pdf')
    pdf(f); pairs(iris); dev.off()
})

res_embed <- microbenchmark({
    f = tempfile(fileext = '.pdf')
    pdf(f); pairs(iris); dev.off()
    embedFonts(f)
})

res_cairo <- microbenchmark({
    f = tempfile(fileext = '.pdf')
    cairo_pdf(f); pairs(iris); dev.off()
})

res_pdf
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       min      lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  16.67764 17.0388 18.05949 17.32904 18.18776 60.2542   100

res_embed
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                                               
#>      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  250.046 252.7647 257.4749 255.2785 259.4858 303.0072   100

res_cairo
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                                   
#>       min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#>  84.25745 86.60512 88.42902 88.36698 89.5705 111.5881   100
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to output your plots as TikZ using the excellent [`tikzDevice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html) package.

From an [rmarkdown](/questions/tagged/rmarkdown) document we can include a [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr) chunk with the device set to `tikz`.

#### example.Rmd

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
  - \usepackage{tikz}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tikzDevice)

# setting the package options so that the font metrics are calculated correctly
options(
  tikzLatexPackages = c(
    getOption("tikzLatexPackages"),
    "\\renewcommand{\\familydefault}{\\sfdefault}"
  )
)
```

# My plot

This text will be set in the default *sans serif* and so will the text found
within the chart below.

```{r, echo=FALSE, dev='tikz'}
pairs(iris)
```
````

You can replace my `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` with whatever latex command you require to set your selected font, such as `\usepackage{charter}`. Just note that you must escape the `\` as in my example above.

#### example.pdf

[image]

#### Alternative

You may want to generate all your plots in advance with another script given you have so many, instead of *knitting* inline at the time of document generation. I do this for a mass run of reports (1,000+) each with about 20 plots.

```
# a more simple example due to output size
library(tikzDevice)
mpg <- mtcars$mpg

tikz(file = "example.tex"); hist(mpg); dev.off()
```

#### example.tex

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1.2 on 2018-02-21 23:32:57
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (216.81,216.81);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (216.81,216.81);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.20] at (120.41,188.07) {\bfseries Histogram of mpg};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (120.41, 15.60) {mpg};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 10.80,114.41) {Frequency};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (216.81,216.81);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 54.47, 61.20) -- (186.34, 61.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 54.47, 61.20) -- ( 54.47, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 80.85, 61.20) -- ( 80.85, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (107.22, 61.20) -- (107.22, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (133.59, 61.20) -- (133.59, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (159.96, 61.20) -- (159.96, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (186.34, 61.20) -- (186.34, 55.20);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 54.47, 39.60) {10};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 80.85, 39.60) {15};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (107.22, 39.60) {20};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (133.59, 39.60) {25};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (159.96, 39.60) {30};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (186.34, 39.60) {35};

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 65.14) -- ( 49.20,163.67);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 65.14) -- ( 43.20, 65.14);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 81.56) -- ( 43.20, 81.56);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 97.98) -- ( 43.20, 97.98);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,114.40) -- ( 43.20,114.40);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,130.83) -- ( 43.20,130.83);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,147.25) -- ( 43.20,147.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,163.67) -- ( 43.20,163.67);

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80, 65.14) {0};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80, 81.56) {2};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80, 97.98) {4};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,114.40) {6};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,130.83) {8};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,147.25) {10};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 49.20, 61.20) rectangle (191.61,167.61);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 54.47, 65.14) rectangle ( 80.85,114.40);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 80.85, 65.14) rectangle (107.22,163.67);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (107.22, 65.14) rectangle (133.59,130.83);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (133.59, 65.14) rectangle (159.96, 81.56);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (159.96, 65.14) rectangle (186.34, 97.98);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

> **N.B.** This is not a complete `.tex` file and is rather designed to be brought in using `\input{example.tex}` or otherwise embedded into a complete document. Also, be mindful of the font metric calculations, the saved `.tex` file may render strangely with different fonts if the metrics are significantly out.